# Show Lagrangian is invariant under infinitesimal $SO(3)$ transformation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, field-theory

Suppose we have the Lagrangian density for a triplet of real scalar fields,
$$
L =  \sum_{a=1}^3 \left[ \frac{1}{2}\partial_\mu\phi_a\partial^\mu\phi_a - \frac{1}{2}\phi_a\phi_a \right].
$$

How do you show that it's invariant under the infinitesimal  $SO(3)$ transformation 
$$
\phi_a \to \phi_a + \theta \epsilon_{abc}n_b\phi_c,
$$

where $\theta$ is a constant and $n_b$ a unit vector. I'm not really sure actually what to do after simply substituting $\phi_a$.

Answer (score 3):

This is easiest done **not** using index notation. Define the column vector

$$
\vec{\phi} =
\begin{pmatrix}
 \phi_1 \\ \phi_2 \\ \phi_3
\end{pmatrix}
$$

The derivative acts on the column vector as $\mathbf{1}_3\partial_\mu$ where $\mathbf{1}_3$ is the identity matrix on the same vector space in which $\vec{\phi}$ lives. That is,

$$
\partial_\mu \vec{\phi} =
\begin{pmatrix}
 \partial_\mu \phi_1 \\ \partial_\mu \phi_2 \\ \partial_\mu \phi_3
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Then we can write the lagrangian as

$$
\mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{2}(\partial_\mu \vec{\phi})^T (\partial_\mu \vec{\phi}) - \frac{1}{2}\vec{\phi}^T \vec{\phi}
$$

Now it can be seen basically by inspection that for $R\in SO(3)$ we have that

$$
\vec{\phi} \stackrel{SO(3)}{\longmapsto} R\vec{\phi} \tag{(a)}\\
\vec{\phi}^T \stackrel{SO(3)}{\longmapsto} \vec{\phi}^T R^T
$$

Under this transfermation, both terms in the lagrangian both terms pick up an $R^TR = \mathbf{1}_3$ sandwiched in the middle. Hence the lagrangian is invariant.

---

Relating to the transformation law using index notation:

$$ \phi_a \to \phi_a + \theta \epsilon_{abc}n_b\phi_c $$

A general $SO(3)$ transformation can be written as

$$
R = e^{-iL_an_a \theta}
$$

so that an **infinitesimal** transformation can be written as

$$
R = 1 -iL_an_a \theta + \mathcal{O}(\theta^2)
$$

Now, in the fundamental representation the generators are given by

$$
(L^a)_{bc} = -\epsilon_{abc}
$$

We therefore see that an infinitesimal SO(3) transformation on $\phi_a$ is given as

$$
\phi_a \to R_{ab}\phi_b = \phi_a + i\theta\epsilon_{abc}n_c \phi_b + \mathcal{O}(\theta^2) \tag{b}
$$

So we see that proving the lagrangian is invariant under (b) is a special case of proving it is invariant under (a).

Comment: Thank you, but how would you relate this to the $+\theta \epsilon_{abc}n_b\phi_c$ part. It seems as if you ignored that, no?

Comment: I'll add an edit. In short they're identical, but you can show it for any SO(3) matrix, not just the infinitesimal transformations.

Comment: While this is correct, I think it misses the point of the exercise, which is presumably to build up lie groups from their generators.

Edit: your edit makes this comment irrelevant.